# How do I set a custom viewport for an iframe?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I want to create an iframe with a custom width.

I don't want the iframe to be responsive (the site embedded in the iframe is responsive) and I want it to appear like a shrunk picture.

I can give you some examples if you wish. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: if width attribute didn't work for you can you please provide examples?

Comment: I think what the OP is suggesting is that the site/page loaded into the iframe needs to be shrunk to fit inside the available iframe window. Or in other words to set the viewport of the page. Howevwer, as far as I am aware this sin't possible using just html since the viewport is declared in the original page itself and not externally. There may be some JQuery plugin for this but I am not aware of any such options.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

you can scale the iframe using css transform. for example, if you'd like to make the page within the iframe to display at half size..

```css
iframe {
  transform: scale(0.5, 0.5);
  height: 1000px;
  width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<iframe src="https://example.com"></iframe>
```

That should display a 1000x1000 viewport of the page shrunk down to a 500x500 iframe.

Comment: your solution helped with my problem

Answer (score 0):

If you have already tried the `width` attribute and that didn't work, try using CSS' `max-width` property.

Example,

**index.html**

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/" class="if"></iframe>
```

**style.css**

```
.if { max-width: 100px; }
```

[Find here live demo](http://jsbin.com/favurogu/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: If you found either mine or Omar's answer helpful, the least you can do is accept it as a best answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry for so delayed reply. Actually my problem is I want to display a 100% iframe width into a  500px container without scrolling and width should still be 100% (though the window would appear much smaller)